# Umbraco - Placing content outside website node?

Tags: architecture, umbraco

I'm trying to re-create a website using Umbraco. For this website I have *news items* which I am storing in a node outside the webroot:

- Content

  - Website Home

    - News
  - Newsmessages

    - Message 1 (created 10-10-2011)
    - Message 2 (created 15-01-2012)

I would like to use URL parameters to filter the list of newsitems to show *or* to show the actual news item.

1. Shows **news section**:

> www.website.com/news

1. Shows **news list** for **2011**:

> www.website.com/news/**2011**

1. Shows **news list** for **October 2011**:

> www.website.com/news/**2011/10**

1. Shows **news detail** for **Message 1**:

> www.website.com/news/2011/10/10/**message-1**

**Can this be done without having to create all content items below /Content/Website Home/News**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add new Area in Umbraco 5 jupiter and add Custom routes in Arearegisteration.cs, there is a package by Sebastiaan Janssen Jupiter as visual Studio Plugin

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/jupiter-as-visual-studio-solution

Use this to convert your web app to MVC application and Right Click on the Area Folder and add a new Area, VS will take care of the rest.
Then add Controller and Custom Routes in AreaRegisteration.cs
For example

```
context.MapRoute(
"ROUTE",
"/{action}/{year}",
new { controller = "ControllerName" }
);
```

if Url is www.website.com/news/2011, the action must be named news and yer will be passed in query string, you can play as you want with the URL.

Hope that Helps,

Sher

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible out of the box with Umbraco. One way this could be accomplished, however, is by use of URL rewrites. You can rewrite your parameters to a query string which can be read by a macro which then, in turn, displays the desired news item(s).

So,

```
www.website.com/news/2011
```

...would be rewritten as something like:

```
www.website.com/news?year=2011
```

...and

```
www.website.com/news/2011/10
```

...would be rewritten as:

```
www.website.com/news?year=2011,month=10
```

..and so on.

The macro on the 'news' page would read the requests from the query string and write out the filtered results.

Comment: I'm using Umbraco 5. Would it perhaps be possible to define a custom route which creates the desired effect? Or am I then bypassing Umbraco too much?

Comment: Ah, my answer is specific to Umbraco 4, Sorry. Sher's answer looks ideal.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, +1 for the answer!